# Conditionally separating a string in R or alternative Regex expressions

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, split

I have a string of 7 dimensions that I want to split into 7 different strings. The string is comma delimited, i.e. there is a comma between each of the dimensions. Ordinarily, to separate the dimensions into different strings, I would just use the separate function and specify that sep = ", ". However, one of my dimensions is a string that in some instances contains a comma, which makes the above method obsolete. Is there a way to potentially conditionally separate the string or a different regex pattern that I could use to still separate the dimensions while maintaining the proper values for each dimension?

Here is a sample of the issue that I am dealing with. Below is an example of the kind of string that I am working with. I have the dimension name, followed by a colon, followed by the value for that dimension. Note that I do not need assistance separating the dimension name from the value, I already have a solution for that:

```
my_str <- "dim1: 1, dim2: a, b, dim3: 3"
```

As you can see, `dim2` has a value of `a, b` so if I use the `separate()` function with `sep = ", "`, I end up with the following three strings:

```
"dim1: 1"
"dim2: a"
"b "
```

when what I want is

```
"dim1: 1"
"dim2: a, b"
"dim3: 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unlist(strsplit(my_str, ",\\s*(?=\\w+:)", perl = TRUE))
[1] "dim1: 1"    "dim2: a, b" "dim3: 3"
```

Comment: Suppose I have a column in a dataframe that is structured the same way as the above string that I supplied, how would I go about creating a new column for each of the new strings?

Comment: @user23356728 `mutate(df, a = strs_plit(your_col, pattern))%>%unnest_wider(a, names_sep='_')`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is with `str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(my_str, "dim.*?(?=,?\\sdim|$)")
```

There are two key elements in the pattern:

- the `?` in `dim.*?` makes the matching 'lazy' in the sense that the matching is halted as soon as the first match is reached (if you leave the `?` out the matching will be 'greedy' and match the whole string)
- `(?=,?\\sdim|$)` is a positive look-ahead that asserts that `dim.*?` must only match **if** there is (i) an optional comma followed by whitespace (`\\s`) and the string `dim` OR (`|`) (ii) by the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the matches using a regex positive lookahead and asserting the same starting pattern with an optional leading comma.

```
\w+:.*?(?=,?\s+\w+:|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+:` Match 1+ word characters
- `.*?` Match any character except a newline, as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `,?\s+\w+:` An optional comma, 1+ word characters followed by `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the lookahead

See the matches in a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zhab4o/1).

For example, using `perl = TRUE` due to the lookahead assertion:

```
my_str <- "dim1: 1, dim2: a, b, dim3: 3"

pattern <- "\\w+:.*?(?=,?\\s+\\w+:|$)"

regmatches(my_str, gregexpr(pattern, my_str, perl = TRUE))
```

Output

```
[1] "dim1: 1"    "dim2: a, b" "dim3: 3"
```